# What is the cause of java.io.IOException and java.io.EOFException errors contantly after starting WSo2 Manager 3.2.0?

Tags: io, wso2, connection, wso2-api-manager, java-io

I am getting the following errors in my Wso2 API Manager and Gateway node logs after starting them up:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-06 07:50:51,388] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver} - Error while reading from the socket. java.io.EOFException: Connection closed from remote end.
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.binary.BinaryMessageConverterUtil.loadData(BinaryMessageConverterUtil.java:39)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver$BinaryTransportReceiver.run(BinaryDataReceiver.java:258)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-06 07:50:52,753] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkHandler} - Exception caught by Mina java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.read(SocketIoProcessor.java:218)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.process(SocketIoProcessor.java:198)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.access$400(SocketIoProcessor.java:45)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor$Worker.run(SocketIoProcessor.java:485)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-06 07:50:52,757] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.MultiVersionProtocolEngine} - Error establishing session java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.read(SocketIoProcessor.java:218)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.process(SocketIoProcessor.java:198)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.access$400(SocketIoProcessor.java:45)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor$Worker.run(SocketIoProcessor.java:485)
        at org.wso2.org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I get this error when starting it with the default deployment.toml and after I have configured it to my deployment needs. It does not seem to affect the functionality of creating/publishing API's and application and subscribing them as well as generating keys so I am not sure what the issue is.

I am currently running this API Manager in a EC2 instance on AWS. If theres any other info needed to help find out why this is happening please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Are you having a distributed setup? If yes, is your Traffic Manager component is fronted with any LBs (ALB or ELB or Classic)?

Comment: Yes it is distributed. I have a management node which is the publisher/devportal and Traffic manager in one, then separate gateways, external gateways and IS.

The Management node is fronted with an ALB and NLB, the ALB is used for connecting to the Publisher/Devportal and the NLB is used for the Traffic Manager connections

Comment: Are these errors producing during the startup of the Gateway nodes? or after a while? I believe the TM is started prior to GW. Can you share the TOML configurations of GW and TM (wanted to verify the port configurations and others related to TM communications)?